# QueryString param value being changed in C# Core

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a C# Core 3 webapi.A variable value is being changed, I am not sure why this could be happening, any ideas?

A GET is sending the following params
`?latitude=33.96568046240656&longitude=-84.325648999999980&distance=50000000`

The controller function is here:

```
        [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<NearbyLocation>> GetNearbyLocations(
        [FromQuery] Double latitude,
        [FromQuery] Double longitude,
        [FromQuery] long distance = 50000,
        [FromQuery] int quantity = 10
        )
    {
        return await _geoTrackService.GetNearbyLocations(latitude, longitude, distance, quantity);
    }
```

The sent variable longitude shows with a value of `-84.325648999999980`

The code variable longitude shows with a value of `-84.325648999999984`

How is this possible?

Comment: If you change the type of `longitude` from `Double` to `Decimal` does it show the desired value? You might find [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) interesting.

Comment: If you dont want to struggle with variable change because of data types. Better to pass data in string and convert that value in double/decimal as per your req.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating point rounding accours. The good thing is that you don't need Decimals to save GPS coordinates. The 5 or6  decimals are usually ok for practical use.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude